# JQuery Remove and Add Class from Object Stored in Variable

Tags: jquery, css, class, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a small jquery script designed to strip an element of a class. My site is running on wordpress however I am getting errors every time I try the window resize handler is called.

```
jQuery(document).ready(

    function watchSize($) {
    var $windowSize = $(window).width();
    var $target = ('#WoodsworthResidenceLogo');

    if ($windowSize < 960 && $target.hasClass('span_2')) {
        $target.removeClass('span_2');
    }

    $(window).resize(
        function() {
        var $windowSize = $(window).width();
        var $target = ('#myelementID');

    if ($windowSize < 960 && $target.hasClass('span_2')) {
        $target.removeClass('span_2');
        } else if ($windowSize > 960 && $target.hasClass('span_2')){
            $target.addClass('span_2');
        }
    });
});
```

It seems most of my error comes from the `$target` variable. Any ideas or suggestions, I'm very new to javascript and jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I'm also unsure of the scope of the variables, thus I have them redeclared in the nested function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax mistake using the jquery library. Your current code is simply assigning a string to `$target`. It would be the same as doing

```
var $target = '#myelementID';
```

You have to replace

```
var $target = ('#WoodsworthResidenceLogo');
```

and

```
var $target = ('#myelementID');
```

by

```
var $target = $('#WoodsworthResidenceLogo');
```

and

```
var $target = $('#myelementID');
```

Notice the `$` in front of the `(..)`. This is an alias for `jQuery`